# Is there a setting to tell Deja dup when to make full backup?

Tags: deja-dup

Is there some settings to tell Deja dup when to make full backup? I using this just two weeks and today hit full backup again. I do backup at least once per day, but usaly 2-5 times per day. And Want full backup for every two month. I wish to prefer when. Is tah possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to control that precisely.  Two main things affect it.  How frequently your automatic backups happen and how long you told DD to keep backups.

By default, with weekly backups and keeping them forever, DD will make a fresh backup every three months.

If you change it to daily backups, I believe it switches to monthly fresh backups.

It sounds like you already make regular manual backups.  I'd say change the automatic backup setting to weekly and continue with your manual backups.  DD should use three month intervals.

In Ubuntu 12.10, DD will always use three months no matter what.  Though you can fiddle with a secret config key to change it if you really want to.